# SQL Count from Two Tables with Inner Join from Third Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

My database has two similar tables with different names. One of the columns contained in both tables is called "zips", which contains a zip code.

I have a different table (US zip code table) where each entry contains a county name, county ID, state, state ID, and zip code.

I need a query that will tell me how many entries in the first two tables match a given county ID, and will group the results by county.

That is, lets say table A has 4 entries for zip code '30017', and table B has 1 entry for '30017'. In the US zip code table, '30017' corresponds to the county name "Gwinnett" and the county ID '839'. When I run the query the desired result is:

```
Gwinnett    5
```

Here is the latest query I've tried. I have no idea what numbers it's returning. It's definitely not what I'm expecting, as I've tried the individual component queries to test the results.

```
SELECT b.County, COUNT(*) as Calls FROM (aLeads a, pLeads p)
INNER JOIN zipCodes b ON a.zip = b.ZipCode
WHERE b.countyID IN (2897, 2146, 839) 
AND a.callDate BETWEEN '2013-10-01' AND '2013-11-30'
GROUP BY b.County
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with the zipcode table, and joining it with aLeads and pLeads:

```
SELECT b.County, COUNT(*) as Calls 
FROM zipCodes b 
INNER JOIN aLeads a ON a.zip = b.ZipCode
INNER JOIN pLeads p ON p.zip = b.ZipCode
WHERE b.countyID IN (2897, 2146, 839) 
GROUP BY b.County
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, and good idea to begin with the zip code table first. However this query returned an empty set. Any other ideas?

Comment: You could make two temporary tables, the first being the zipcode joined with the aLeads.  The second being the zipcode joined with the pLeads.  Each temp table would have the zip code, and the count.  Finally, join the two temp tables together, and add up the counts.

Comment: Its really close to being correct. After some analysis it seems like the only issue with the query you proposed is in the date criteria. I think it returns an empty set because the date clause only considers table a
`AND a.callDate BETWEEN '2013-10-01' AND '2013-11-30'`

Comment: Yes it certainly does.  I simply copied and pasted the sql query you posted, and added the join in.  I'll edit the query in this answer to remove the date criteria.